# Blender 2.8 Animation: How to select keyframes from inside the UI like in 2.79

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

In Blender 2.79, dragging your mouse in the middle of the frame would scrub through frames. Now in 2.78 it does a box select. In order to scrub through frames again I must drag my mouse across the frame numbers at the top.

How can I switch the frame scrubbing back to what it was like in 2.79?

Comment: Holding down **shift key** and RMB (left select style) could do the job

Answer (score 1):

As commented, the default setup in 2.80 is to use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> in the middle of the animation related editors to change the current frame.

If you want to change this, you can adjust the keymap settings in the User Preferences.

You can find the frame change under animation.

[image: frame change settings]

And the selection settings are under Dopesheet -> Dopesheet(Global)

[image: selection settings]

By changing the selection settings to use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> and the frame change to use <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> you can continue working the way you remember.